# Codeigniter WHERE OR AND with Array from Session

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following array in the `session->userdata('usershop')`:

```
Array
(
  [shop_chain] => 9001
  [shop_code] => 1
)
Array
(
  [shop_chain] => 9002
  [shop_code] => 1
)
Array
(
  [shop_chain] => 9001
  [shop_code] => 2
)
Array
(
  [shop_chain] => 9001
  [shop_code] => 3
)
```

I have to select data from another table:
[image]

Has to take only the rows where the `chain_code` and `shop_code` matches from this table.

I tried this:

```
foreach ($this->session->userdata('usershop') as $usr => $usrshop) {
        $where = $this->db->where(array('chain_code' => $usrshop['shop_chain'], 'shop_code' => $usrshop['shop_code']));
    }
    return $this->db->get('wd2dbschema_config.cfg_shop')->result();
```

But all this does is taking wrong rows as the result is this:

```
SELECT * FROM "wd2dbschema_config"."cfg_shop" WHERE "chain_code" = '9001' AND "shop_code" = '1' AND "chain_code" = '9002' AND "shop_code" = '1' AND "chain_code" = '9001' AND "shop_code" = '2' AND "chain_code" = '9001' AND "shop_code" = '3'
```

How do I do this so that it takes only the matching rows?

Like so:

```
SELECT * FROM "wd2dbschema_config"."cfg_shop" WHERE ("chain_code" = '9001' AND "shop_code" = '1') OR ("chain_code" = '9002' AND "shop_code" = '1') OR ("chain_code" = '9001' AND "shop_code" = '2') OR ("chain_code" = '9001' AND "shop_code" = '3')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using active record you can do so,make sure you pass second parameter in `where()/or_where` as null so the active record will not look for the comparison of first parameter,and third parameter as FALSE so active record will not add additional bacticks to the where clause expressions

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($this->session->userdata('usershop') as $usr => $usrshop) {
    if($i==0){
        $this->db->where(" (chain_code = '" . $usrshop['shop_chain'] . "' AND shop_code = '" . $usrshop['shop_code'] . "') ", null, FALSE);
    }else{
        $this->db->or_where(" (chain_code = '" . $usrshop['shop_chain'] . "' AND shop_code = '" . $usrshop['shop_code'] . "') ", null, FALSE);
    }
    $i++;
}
return $this->db->get('wd2dbschema_config.cfg_shop')->result();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like

```
foreach ($this->session->userdata('usershop') as $usr => $usrshop) {
    $where = $this->db->where(array('chain_code' => $usrshop['shop_chain'], 'shop_code' => $usrshop['shop_code']));
    $data[] = $this->db->get('wd2dbschema_config.cfg_shop')->result();
}
return $data;
```

You either execute the every where condition once and need to catch them in an array and after completion of the loop you can directly pass it.